# Optimization Help : SQL Query to display minimum prices per country

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, query-optimization

I have developed a Tender management System sort of code for one of my client. This is the piece of code :

```
try {
    Connection con = Mycon.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("TRUNCATE tempcalcplan");
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.clearBatch();
    ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tempcalcplan SELECT v.conid,c.conname, v.rate, v.venid FROM venprices v LEFT JOIN  country c ON c.conid = v.conid WHERE (v.conid, v.rate) IN ( SELECT v.conid, MIN(v.rate) FROM venprices v GROUP BY v.conid) GROUP BY v.conid");
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.clearBatch();
    ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from tempcalcplan");

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This piece of code is designed to function as :

1. Empty the table `tempcalcplan`(Assuming that previous results are stored.)
2. Generating desired data with the help of 2 different tables(Tables are shown below) and storing it in the `tempcalcplan` table
3. Displaying the results of `tempcalcplan` table on a jTable.

Here Are the `country` and `tempcalcplan` table.

1. `country` (Contains 30,000 records)

   ```
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | conid   | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
   | conname | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   ```
2. `tempcalcplan` (Contains 1,80,000+ Records)

   ```
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | conid   | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
   | conname | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | rate    | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | venid   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   ```
3. `venprices`

   ```
   +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | conid | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
   | rate  | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | venid | varchar(50)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
   +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   ```

The results take up to 12-15 minutes to show in the jTable.
I want reduce it to 1-2 minutes.

Comment: Smells like [_Groupwise max_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/) -- that link shows how to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query that probably takes the most time:

```
INSERT INTO tempcalcplan
    SELECT v.conid, c.conname, v.rate, v.venid
    FROM venprices v LEFT JOIN
         country c
         ON c.conid = v.conid
    WHERE (v.conid, v.rate) IN ( SELECT v.conid, MIN(v.rate) FROM venprices v GROUP BY v.conid) GROUP BY v.conid");
```

My guess is that the `WHERE` clause is causing the problem.  Try moving this to the `FROM` clause:

```
    SELECT v.conid, c.conname, v.rate, v.venid
    FROM venprices v LEFT JOIN
         country c
         ON c.conid = v.conid JOIN
         (SELECT v.conid, MIN(v.rate) as rate
          FROM venprices v
          GROUP BY v.conid
         ) vr
         ON v.conid = vr.conid and v.rate = vr.rate;
```

I think your indexes are set up fine for this query.

Comment: I don't have any indexes set up. To be honest i actually don't know how to use indexes.

Comment: @ArpitPorwal . . . Primary keys generate indexes.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff, With a few modifications, the complete operation was performed in less than 2 seconds. But When I append `insert into tempcalcplan` before the query, it doesn't get inserted into the table.

Comment: @ArpitPorwal . . . It should; that is how `insert` works.  The only way it would not be inserted is if the `insert` generated an error or if a trigger caused it to do something else.

Answer (score 1):

[Gordon's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39659846/1797579) does look like a major improvement over what you are currently using.

```
SELECT v.conid, c.conname, v.rate, v.venid
FROM venprices v LEFT JOIN
     country c
     ON c.conid = v.conid JOIN
     (SELECT v.conid, MIN(v.rate) as rate
      FROM venprices v
      GROUP BY v.conid
     ) vr
     ON v.conid = vr.conid and v.rate = vr.rate;
```

I'm not confident that you already have the index required though. Run the following command in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `venprices` ADD INDEX `RatesPerConid` (`conid`,`rate`)
```

You should see the performance improve drastically after creating that index. Note `RatesPerConid` is the name of the index. You can change it to whatever you like.

Caveat: If it is possible have multiple instances of the same minimum `rate` for a given `conid`, you may need to change `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT` at the top of the query (not in the query with the GROUP BY).